# Why is it, only the last row of the table is updated/deleted when query's executed?

Tags: php, mysql

This is quite a mystery for me! HAHA. Why is it, only the last row of my table is being updated/deleted when I execute the query? Codes are functioning, it's just that, only the last/most recent record can be modified. I've encountered this problem before and it was fixed the next day when I restarted my pc [Well, I didnt know how it happened HAHA]. Now its becoming my problem again.

Could anyone help me with thisssss, please...

This is my **AdminPAevaluation.php** page:

This is the **HTML** part:

```
<?php
$selectquery="select * from tbl_annualevaluation;";
$selectrs=mysqli_query($con,$selectquery) or die ("Cannot execute query.");
$selectrows=mysqli_fetch_array($selectrs);
?>
<tr>
<th>DESCRIPTION</th>
<th>GRADE (%)</th>
<th>SALARY APPRAISAL (%)</th>
<th>UPDATE
</th>
<th>DELETE</th>
</tr>
```

Here's the **PHP** part:

```
<?php do{ ?>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $selectrows['description'];?>" name="txtdescription" class="textbox1" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $selectrows['grade'];?>" name="txtgrade" class="textbox1" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $selectrows['salaryAppraisal'];?>" name="txtsalaryAppraisal" class="textbox1" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="UPDATE" class="button1" name="update"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="DELETE" class="button1" name="delete"/></td>
</tr>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $selectrows['idtbl_annualevaluation'];?>" name="txtidtbl_annualevaluation" />

<?php } while($selectrows=mysqli_fetch_array($selectrs)); ?></table>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>

<?php
$descId=$_POST['txtidtbl_annualevaluation'];
$txtdesc=$_POST['txtdescription'];
$txtgrade=$_POST['txtgrade'];
$txtsalaryAppraisal=$_POST['txtsalaryAppraisal'];

//this is the block codes for insert
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    $insertdesc="insert into tbl_annualevaluation (description) values ('$_POST[new]');";
    $insertdescrs=mysqli_query($con,$insertdesc) or mysqli_error();
    header("location:AdminPAevaluation.php");
}

//this is the block codes for delete.   
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
```

This part, I think my codes here are correct and names are correctly placed too, so i dont know why it isn't working properly... Hmmmmmmm

```
$deletedesc="delete from tbl_annualevaluation where idtbl_annualevaluation='$descId';";
$deletedescrs=mysqli_query($con,$deletedesc);
header("location:AdminPAevaluation.php");

}
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$updatedesc="update tbl_annualevaluation set description='$txtdesc', grade='$txtgrade', salaryAppraisal='$txtsalaryAppraisal' where idtbl_annualevaluation='$descId';";
$updatedescrs=mysqli_query($con,$updatedesc) or mysqli_error();
header("location:AdminPAevaluation.php");
}
?>
```

I'm pretty sure that the column names, tables and all--were correctly/appropriately specified.

Comment: **where idtbl_annualevaluation='$descId'** is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's all part of the same form, so it's probably only reading the very last hidden value. You forgot to make the loop create a new form whenever it begins.

```
<?php do{ ?>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $selectrows['description'];?>" name="txtdescription" class="textbox1" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $selectrows['grade'];?>" name="txtgrade" class="textbox1" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $selectrows['salaryAppraisal'];?>" name="txtsalaryAppraisal" class="textbox1" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="UPDATE" class="button1" name="update"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="DELETE" class="button1" name="delete"/></td>
</tr>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $selectrows['idtbl_annualevaluation'];?>" name="txtidtbl_annualevaluation" />
</form>

<?php } while($selectrows=mysqli_fetch_array($selectrs)); ?></table>
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's what I found: the `<form>` tag is missing.

Comment: The close tag is also outside of the loop, each row should be a separate form unless each text input has a unique name which is then sorted by the PHP afterwards to determine the correct row.

Comment: Thanks Sir! I moved the </form> tag before the while loop already. It's still the same results... Hmm

Comment: Did you add the form creation at the top of each loop?

Comment: Anyways Sir, I think that's the problem with my code. I reviewed my previous work [the correct one] and I've noticed the placement of the <form> tags. HAHA. Thanks Sir. God bless.